# How to see the list of deleted files in SVN log?

Tags: list, file, svn

When performing a delete operation on an SVN directory, the delete operation returns a list of deleted files:

```
D         folder/test
D         folder/test/images
D         folder/test/images/gif.gif
D         folder/test/images/jpeg.jpeg
D         folder/test/images/jpg.jpg
D         folder/test/images/pdf.pdf
D         folder/test/images/png.png
D         folder/test/images/svg.svg
```

After that, if I commit the changes and try to do a *verbose* log for the revision in which the files were deleted:

```
svn log https://svn.remote.repository/repos/repo -r 12345 -v
```

It only returns the folder which was deleted:

```
Changed paths:
      D /root/branches/branch/folder/test
```

How do I get a list of the deleted files, like in the original delete operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `svn log --depth infinity --diff -r 12345 -v`.

See [--depth](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.depth):

> --depth ARG
>
> Instructs Subversion to limit the scope of an operation to a particular tree depth. ARG is one of empty (only the target itself),
> files (the target and any immediate file children thereof), immediates
> (the target and any immediate children thereof), or infinity (the
> target and all of its descendants—full recursion).